# DrawerLayout NavigationView No drawer view found with gravity LEFT

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I have implemented a drawer layout whereby when I click a navigation view item a tab layout opens up. The tablayout comes in fine but the problem is when i click the back button of the tab layout the application crashes with No drawer view found with gravity LEFT. Also I have noticed that there is a bit of a lag when the navigation drawer closes when the tab layout comes in, the drawer does not close smoothly.

Below is my java code and xml:

```
public class Navigation extends AppCompatActivity implements
        ItemFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener,
        SortFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{

    private static final String TAG = Navigation.class.getSimpleName();
    Toolbar toolbar;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private TextView mCounter;
    private ImageView cart;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    public int id, tabPosition = 0, tabPositionNavigation = 0;
    private String drinkToSort = "empty";
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    private LocalStore localStore;
    private String userName, email, location;
    private String phone;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.navigation);

        localStore = new LocalStore(this);
        id = localStore.getLoggedInUser().getId();
        userName = localStore.getLoggedInUser().getUserName();
        email = localStore.getLoggedInUser().getEmail();
        phone = localStore.getLoggedInUser().getPhone();
        Log.i(TAG,"USERDATA" + "[" + id + userName + email + phone + location + "]");

        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                toolbar,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getActionBar().setTitle("hello");
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getActionBar().setTitle("hello");
            }
        };

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            this.tabPosition = extras.getInt("tabPosition");
            this.tabPositionNavigation = extras.getInt("tabPositionNavigation");
            this.drinkToSort = extras.getString("drinkToSort");
            Log.d(TAG, tabPosition + tabPositionNavigation + drinkToSort);
        }
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("drinkToSort", drinkToSort);
        LiquorFragment obj = new LiquorFragment();
        obj.setArguments(bundle);
        int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels/2;

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new NavigationFragment()).commit();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.details_activity, menu);
        RelativeLayout badgeLayout = (RelativeLayout) menu.findItem(R.id.cart_no).getActionView();
        mCounter = (TextView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        Log.d("sameSelectionCount", CartCounter.getCounter()+"");
        mCounter.setText(""+CartCounter.getCounter());
        cart = (ImageView) badgeLayout.findViewById(R.id.cart);
        cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("cart_no","cart_no");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShoppingList.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        else {
            super.onBackPressed();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // analytics
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //TabFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
        Log.d("landposzq",tabPositionNavigation + "");
        if (tabPositionNavigation != 0){
            if (tabPositionNavigation == 1){
                NavigationFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            } else if (tabPositionNavigation == 2){
                NavigationFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            } else if (tabPositionNavigation == 3){
                NavigationFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            } else if (tabPositionNavigation == 4){
                NavigationFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
            } else if (tabPositionNavigation == 5){
                NavigationFragment.viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
            }
        }

    }
}


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!--Main content-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/qb"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--Navigation Drawer-->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_drawer"
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:itemTextColor="#000000"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/qb"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/balloon4"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/free_drinks"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffff99"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/direction"
                android:height="60dp"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="GET FREE DRINKS"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Use your globally defined variable of DrawerLayout in onBackPressed() method also.

Comment: I have given an answer. Please refer that.

Comment: it still fails, when i press the back phone button it works but when i press the toolbar back icon it crashes

Comment: Then add your stack trace here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your onBackPressed() method as below :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }

}
```